# Python code modification to make output file as XML and not CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv

The following code gives me the data for all the folders, subfolders and files along with the size of each. Currently, this is saving the data in a CSV file. But I believe this kind of data (nested data) is best suited for XML. I am not very well versed with XML. Any help to modify the code will be appreciated

```
import os
import csv

def GetHumanReadable(size,precision=2):
    suffixes=['KB','MB','GB','TB']
    suffixIndex = 0 
    while size > 1024:
        suffixIndex += 1 #increment the index of the suffix
        size = size/1024.0 #apply the division
    return "%.*f %s"%(precision,size,suffixes[suffixIndex])

def list_files(startpath):
    with open('output.csv','w') as file:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
            level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ,' * 4 * (level)
            file.write('{}{}/\n'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
            subindent = ' ,' * 4 * (level + 1)
            for f in sorted(files, key=lambda f: os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f)):
                converted_size = GetHumanReadable(os.path.getsize(root + os.sep + f))
                file.write('{}{},{}\n'.format(subindent, f, converted_size))
```

Comment: try to use [xml.etree.elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of import xml.etree.ElementTree to make an output xml file.
here is an example

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data='''
<root>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The quick</F>
    <F LV="1">brown</F>
    <F LV="2">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The lazy</F>
    <F LV="1">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
</root>
'''
root= ET.XML(data)

with open('d:\output.xml', 'wb') as file:
    Et.ElementTree(root).write(file, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```